# this.name is not working in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I did sample example with a list of menu items.Here what i am need is **to get  a name of menu item when click the list of menu items using `this.name`.** Here `this.name is not working.So please see the below code and suggest me what to do?

Template Code :

```
 <template name="main">
   <div id="menu" style="float:left;">
      <div class="square {{ selected 0 }}">{{ square 0 }}</div>
      <div class="square {{ selected 1 }}">{{ square 1 }}</div>
      <div class="square {{ selected 2 }}">{{ square 2 }}</div>
      <div class="square {{ selected 3 }}">{{ square 3 }}</div>


      <div class="square {{ selected 4 }}">{{ square 4 }}</div>
      <div class="square {{ selected 5 }}">{{ square 5 }}</div>
      <div class="square {{ selected 6 }}">{{ square 6 }}</div>
      <div class="square {{ selected 7 }}">{{ square 7 }}</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

CSS :
    .square {
        cursor: pointer;
        width:200px;
        height:20px;
        border:4px solid #eeeee8;
        border-radius: 4px;
        -moz-border-radius: 4px;
        margin: 4px;
       // float:left;
        text-align: center;
        background-color:green;//#eeeee8;
        font-size: 20px;
    }

JS Code :

```js
var SPLASH = [
    'Home', 'Clients', 'Menu', 'About Us',
    'Contact Us', 'Others', 'Help', 'ETC',
]

Template.main.square = function (i) {
    //console.log("Selected square item="+i);
    return SPLASH[i];
};

Template.main.events({
    'click .square': function (evt, t) {

        evt.preventDefault();

        Session.set("selectedMenuName", this.name);
        console.log("***selectedMenuName=***" + this.name);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're setting `evt.target.innerHTML` to `var Name`, but you're calling `this.name'.
'Name !== name`

Also, shouldn't you be returning `Session.get('selectedMenuName')` instead of `Session.equals`?

Comment: yeah but this.name is different than Name.Here Name variable and this.name is predefined.@davegonzalez